# Android How can I split this database table column with multiple delimiters?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Currently I have a huge string-array with multiple items, each formatted like this, which I am going to store into a table. How can I query and split this string? I want to split each section between | + *

I am using sqlite

```
<string-array name="values">
    <item>TERM 1|MATH 1234+Introduction Mathematics*This course is an introduction to math</item>
</string-array>
```

I am going to show each section on different activities. For example

First activity: User chooses TERM 1
"TERM 1" is passed as an extra to second activity

Second activity: Get extra, query for TERM 1 courses and display 7 courses
 User chooses MATH 1234, and MATH 1234 is passed as an extra

Third activity: Get extra, query for Math 1234
display "Intro to mathematics" as the title and "This is an introduction to math" in text view.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expression from `java.util.regex` package.

As your delimiters are not unified inside the string, you'll have to split the string several times, using the corresponding delimiter for each sub-step.

Comment: maybe. As old perl(1) guy, I prefer the specific tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "TERM 1|MATH 1234+Introduction Mathematics*This course is an introduction to math";
String[] parts = s.split("[|+*]");
```

Should get you

```
[TERM 1, MATH 1234, Introduction Mathematics, This course is an introduction to math]
```

Regarding passing extras between Activities, I'd suggest just storing the data into SQLite.